# select box on IE 10 pre release hides after some time

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

when you click on a select box it opens up with all options
but when you select one option the option list hides after
a long 3-4 second delay.

is this an IE specific behaviour ??

Comment: is there code with this question? Can this answer be found with an extensive google search perhaps?

Comment: there are no event handlers directly attached to select box, its just a plain form with multiple form elements including select box.

Comment: IE 10 pre-repease? God, why?

Comment: i know, but i dont have option to upgrade :(

Comment: you need to expand this question further or risk it being closed as there is no code associated showing what may be happening in the background causing the errors. Right now it lacks sufficient information to be considered a "complete" question.

Comment: there are no javascript errors on console. this behaviour is on all the select boxes in application, even if i inject some select boxes using console, i get same behaviour. does this info help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is an IE specific issue, you might have some code to hide it. Otherwise IE won't do that itself.

Comment: there is not code that explicitly hides select box. if i close IE tab and reopen again then it works fine, after some more fiddling it slows down.